# Unable to find the element in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

[[Img1[][Img2[Img3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGX7g.png)I was trying to get the  element by its link text. But getting below Exception.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"CFDSDSR"}

I tried following by switching to the frame, but then it gave frame not found but the frame exists:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("main");
driver1.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

XPath:

> /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLuJX.png)/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLuJX.png)/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLuJX.png)/a

Code:
 Try 1:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("CFDSDSR")).click();
```

Try 2:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/a")).click();
```

HTML:

```
<frame name="main" marginheight="4" marginwidth="4" src="../utilityintro.jsp?title=Miscellaneous Utilities">
..........
..........
<a href="javascript:openpopup('CFDSDSR', '15003', 'COMPLETE')" class="lbcontext">CFDSDSR</a>
..........

..........
</frame>
```

Tried storing all elements from that frame into ArrayList even that did not work.

Expected:
It should select that  element and after clicking pop-up should open.
Actual:
NoSuchElementException

Comment: Would you post a proper HTML snippet, please?

Comment: You wouldn't typically search by tag *content* like this.  Can you not search by class lbcontext instead?  Are there multiple tags with this class?

Comment: Tried searching by class name too. still did not work

Comment: no.. i tried storing them in ArrayList but that did not give any results

Answer (score 1):

I was successful with By.PartialLinkText("xyz");
try it.

```
driver.findElement(By.PartialLinkText("CFDSDSR");
```

hope your issue will be solved

Comment: I tried that too. In fact, I used the same trick for my other elements that worked. But in this case that's not working, I suppose since it is JS call.

Comment: have there more elements with link text 'CFDSDSR'?

Comment: By.cssSelector("a[href="javascript:openpopup('CFDSDSR', '15003', 'COMPLETE')"]")

Answer (score 0):

Is it classic problem, clic on `a href` do not work if is it javascript action. You need clic by javascrit

```
driver.waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("..."));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("document.evaluate(\"" + "...").replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0).click();");
```

Comment: Could you explain the second line, please

Comment: @SanjayGunagi, https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_%C3%A0_l_utilisation_de_XPath_avec_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here now. 
After digging a lot into the code I made it work by adding one more line in the code.
Before  driver.switchTo().frame("main"); I added driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); and it gave me expected result. :)